# Google Cloud Storage bucket ID

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I can't find Google Cloud Storage bucket ID in my Google Play Console account. I am new to Play console. where can i find it?

I tried finding it in play console - download reports section but it isn't showing there.

Comment: May be Download reports - find any app and click on a link

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. Here are the complete instructions:

1. Download reports
2. Select an app
3. At the bottom of the page there should be a `Direct report URIs`

Example:

```
gs://pubsite_prod_58148478376/reviews
```

Your Cloud Storage Bucket ID should be as follows:

```
pubsite_prod_58148478376
```

Note: If you just uploaded your first application, it may take a while before the report is generated and visible.

Comment: For me, the default tab in Download Reports doesn't contain any data (yet). I had to go to the Financial tab to see the "Direct report URIs:" value.

Comment: This answer details how we can add Google Cloud Storage URI to App Annie as well

Comment: I believe this has changed, there is now a link called "Copy Cloud Storage URI"

Answer (score 1):

Bucket id is nothing but your bucket name.

1. go to your cloud storage
2. You can see the available bucket on your account